# Can Doctrine's ODM reference one document without declaring type?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm using Doctrine 2.10 with Symfony 4. I can see in the documentation for [Doctrine's ODM references](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/reference-mapping.html#mixing-document-types) that a `referenceMany` relationship can store different types of documents in references by omitting the `targetDocument` option:

```php
/* @Document */
Class User
{
    /* @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Account") */
    private accounts = [];
}
```

becomes

```php
/* @Document */
Class User
{
    /* @ReferenceMany */
    private accounts = [];
}
```

It seems that the same can't be achieved with the `referenceOne` relationship. When I use `referenceOne` without the `targetDocument` option, I get a mapping exception:

> Class '' does not exist

Ideally I'd like to be able to use the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` options so that the Account document owns the relationship, and is able to reference either a User or a Company, which share some properties. The following doesn't work, but is there a way to achieve what it represents?

```php
/* @Document */
class User
{
    /* @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Account", mappedBy="owner") */
    private $accounts = [];
}

/* @Document */
class Company
{
    /* @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Account", mappedBy="owner") */
    private $accounts = [];
}

/* @Document */
class Account
{
    /* @ReferenceOne(inversedBy="accounts") */
    private $owner;
}
```

Comment: Try removing `inversedBy="accounts"` from the `$owner` property as it may make ODM to look into not specified class for the field "accounts".

Comment: Unfortunately the error quoted above is the result of omitting all options from `@ReferenceOne`, including `inversedBy`.

Comment: Would you mind opening an issue (or better yet, a PR with a failing test case) in https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues then? It sounds like a shortcoming on our end.

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/2040